sequelize cli migrate error for You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the righ
when i try to db:migrate using sequelize cli for this it give me this error
first i have created model using this
npx sequelize model:generate --name Register --attributes UserName:string Email:string Password:string Weight:string Lifestyle:string Goal:string Height:string  BMI:string BirthDate:date Age:number Gender:string
error is ===> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, LifeStyle VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, Goal VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `H...' at line 1
model file
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Register extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  Register.init({
    UserName: {
     type: DataTypes.STRING,
     allowNull:false,
    },
    Email: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
      unique:true,
    },
    Password: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    Weight: {
      type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    LifeStyle: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    Goal: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    Height: {
      type:DataTypes.NUMBER,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    BMI: {
     type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
     allowNull:false,
    },
    BirthDate: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull:false,
    },
    Age: {
     type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
     allowNull:false,
    },
    Gender: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false,
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Register',
  });
  return Register;
};```



**migration file**





    'use strict';
    /** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */
    module.exports = {
      async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.createTable('Registers', {
          id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
          },
          UserName: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull:false,
          },
          Email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull:false,
            unique:true,
          },
          Password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull:false,
          },
          Weight: {
            type: Sequelize.NUMBER,
            allowNull:false,
          },
          LifeStyle: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull:false,
          },
          Goal: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull:false,
          },
          Height: {
            type: Sequelize.NUMBER,
            allowNull:false,
          },
          BMI: {
            type: Sequelize.NUMBER,
            allowNull:false,
          },
          BirthDate: {
            type: Sequelize.DATE,
            allowNull:false,
          },
          Age: {
            type: Sequelize.NUMBER,
            allowNull:false,
          },
          Gender: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull:false,
          },
          createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          },
          updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          }
        });
      },
      async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('Registers');
      }
    };





how can i solve this problem?



Please add the complete generated SQL query
